# Revert toggle (button) state without getting stuck in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make sure that the front-end button state doesn't give wrong impression to the user if there occurs an error during Ajax call.

There maybe cases when a Jquery AJax call fails due to no internet connection, for example. I would like the button to revert to the original state if an error occurs and no changes were made on the server.

This is a normal bootstrap button that I customized to make it a toggle button. 
I am able to toggle it to ON/OFF on click. I tried to simulate `click` on the said button to make it toggle back to the original state in case Ajax call failed.

HTML part:

```
    <button type="button" id="toggle-verify-mobile"  data-toggle="button" {% if request.session.skip_verification %} class="active btn btn-lg btn-toggle" aria-pressed="true" {% else %} class="btn btn-lg btn-toggle" aria-pressed="false" {% endif %} autocomplete="off">
    <div class="handle"></div>
```

JQuery part:

```
$(function() {
    $("#toggle-verify-mobile").on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#toggle-verify-mobile-error').html('<br/>')
        var csrf = $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
        current_state = $(this).hasClass('active')
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{% url 'my_app:ajax_skip_mobile_verification' %}",
        data: {
            'current_state': current_state,
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf
        },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        // Success stuff here
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
        if (current_state) { // If error occurred then set the same state as it was
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $('#toggle-verify-mobile').click();  // THIS GOES INTO LOOP
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("active");
            $('#toggle-verify-mobile').click();   // THIS GOES INTO LOOP
        }
    }
  });
    });
});
```

As you can see this will loop because `click()` will again call this Ajax and that would again call `click()`

**EDIT**

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cdkj5axh/)

Comment: Can you please provide jsfiddle for it.

Comment: @AlokMali added

Comment: Please check once this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aalok123/xyuvLaqr/27/
I have commented on some lines.

Comment: @AlokMali I am not able to toggle the button.

Answer (score 0):

That endless click loop behavior you get is normal because you're attaching a click event handler on `#toggle-verify-mobile` and on your `error` callback you're making it click again on the same `#toggle-verify-mobile` thus calling the same ajax request in an endless loop.

So if you want to toggle button animation depending on `current_state`, you just have to intervert the `addClass` and `removeClass` in `if` conditions and in your `error` callback you don't need to trigger that click event to toggle the animation because it will end up in the endless loop you're actually facing.

Also, if you don't give a context element to the ajax function, you won't be able to make the toggle animation as `$(this)` will pertain to a an object that represents the Ajax settings used in the call (more infos on that [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-url-settings)), so pass `this` as a reference to the toggle button.

Here is a working example :

```js
 $(function() {
  $("#toggle-verify-mobile").on("click", function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $('#toggle-verify-mobile-error').html('<br/>')
   var csrf = $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
   current_state = $(this).hasClass('active')
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "{% url 'my_app:ajax_skip_mobile_verification' %}",
   data: {
    'current_state': current_state,
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf
   },
   context: this, //passing $("#toggle-verify-mobile") to the callbacks so it can be retrived like : $(this)
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
   if(!data.has_error) {
    if (current_state) { // If no error occurred then set the same toggle the state
     $(this).removeClass("active");     
    } else {
     $(this).addClass("active");
    }
   } else {
    $('#toggle-verify-mobile-error').html(data.message)
    if (current_state) { // If error occurred then set the same state as it was
     $(this).removeClass("active");
    } else {
     $(this).addClass("active");     
    }
   }
  },
  error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
   if (current_state) { // If error occurred then set the same state as it was
   $(this).removeClass("active");
   setTimeout(function(element){ $(element).addClass("active"); }, 500, this);
   
  } else {
   $(this).addClass("active");
   setTimeout(function(element){ $(element).removeClass("active"); }, 500, this);    
  }
  }
   });
  });
 });
```

```css
.btn-toggle {
  color: #6b7381;
  background: #bdc1c8;
  margin: 0 1rem;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  height: 2.5rem;
  width: 7rem;
  border-radius: 2.5rem;
}
.btn-toggle:focus,
.btn-toggle.focus,
.btn-toggle:focus.active,
.btn-toggle.focus.active {
  outline: none !important;
}


.btn-toggle:before,
.btn-toggle:after {
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  width: 7rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.25s;
}
.btn-toggle:before {
  content: 'OFF';
  left: 1rem;
}
.btn-toggle:after {
  content: 'ON';
  right: 1rem;
  opacity: 0;
}
.btn-toggle > .handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.3125rem;
  left: 0.3125rem;
  width: 1.875rem;
  height: 1.875rem;
  border-radius: 1.875rem;
  background: #fff;
  transition: left 0.25s;
}
.btn-toggle.active {
  transition: background-color 0.25s;
}
.btn-toggle.active > .handle {
  left: 4.8125rem;
  transition: left 0.25s;
}
.btn-toggle.active:before {
  opacity: 0;
}
.btn-toggle.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-toggle:before,
.btn-toggle:after {
  color: #fff;
}
.btn-toggle.active {
  background-color: #46D89E;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css' integrity='sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU' crossorigin='anonymous'>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="toggle-verify-mobile"  data-toggle="button" {% if request.session.skip_appointment_verification %} class="active btn btn-lg btn-toggle" aria-pressed="true" {% else %} class="btn btn-lg btn-toggle" aria-pressed="false" {% endif %} autocomplete="off">
       <div class="handle"></div>
      </button>
      <span><br/><span id="toggle-verify-mobile-error" class="text-danger"><br/></span></span>
```

Comment: I know that `click()` trigger will end in loop. That is what is my problem. I can remove that but I still need to achieve what that is achieving on first call, revert to the original state(off or on). 
Your code doesn't achieve that part. I am already able to toggle that button. The problem is like when there is no internet connection and the user clicks on that button the button should go from On to Off and come back to Off from On when the Ajax calls encounters error(no internet)

Comment: Well, if you add the class `active` to the button it turns to *ON*, if you remove that class it turns to *OFF*, that is how you can achieve that and my code does it.
The thing is that your `current_state = $(this).hasClass('active')` variable doesn't check if there was an error in the request, it just checks if the button has the `active` class and then removes it or adds as a consequence.

Comment: If there is no internet the user won't even be able to execute the code as its browser will not be able to download jQuery/bootstrap and the other dependencies your app requires so there is no sense in taking that scenario into account...

Comment: I am taking into account the situation when the user has opened the page where that toggle button is and while he has it open internet disconnects or even some other error occurs on the server when there is internet connection.

Comment: Ok, so you can set a timeout of like 500ms and then add/remove the `active` class so the animation will toggle the button back to its original ON or OFF state, please watch the updated code.